codebase written in flutter, uninstalled and reinstalled cmake. I keep getting an error stating cmake is outdated. How do I fix this?
powershell:
PS pathway/to/file> flutter build windows --release --target=lib/Launcher/main.dart

CMake Error at flutter/ephemeral/.plugin_symlinks/record_windows/windows/CMakeLists.txt:5 (cmake_minimum_required):
  CMake 3.23 or higher is required.  You are running version
  3.20.21032501-MSVC_2


Building Windows application...                                  1,043ms
Unable to generate build files
PS pathway/to/file> cmake --version
cmake version 3.30.5

Does anyone know what might be the cause of this? I've tried completely removing cmake and installing a fresh copy (via windows x64 installer at https://cmake.org/download/). Yet before and after every time I go to build this project I get an error stating I'm running 3.23. I only have 1 environment variable that leads to 3.30.5. I am at a complete loss. When I make my own projects this never happens. The one time I clone a git repo from a friend in an attempt to help him solve a bug I have this problem and can't even compile the project. Any information is appreciated. I'm willing to bet it's something real simple that the two of us are just missing.
operating system: win10
EDIT:
I have since found out for whatever reason, using Powershell in VS Code causes problems. I was working on another flutter project and several days later, I did something that caused this one to break. I was able to run the project in Cmd, Powershell and Android Studio's terminal after breaking it in VS Code's terminal (after a frantic four hours of misery). So I guess my question now is does anyone have any information on to what could be causing VS code's Powershell (and only VS Code's terminal) to break?
